# Open a local file in browser by just typing a keyword mapped to the file's address

Tags: html

I spent a good amount of time looking but couldn't find an answer. Probably not using the right terms to search which is not helping. This is what I want to do: 
 1. I open a browser (specifically interested for IE8 if somebody wants to know). 
 2. I type *'Game'*, and nothing else, in the Address bar and hit Enter. 
 3. HTML file **Game.html**, which is present on my desktop, opens in my browser. 
 Can this be done? If yes, how?

Comment: I think you can edit in a [`hosts` entry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034), but I think even then you'd need a server of some kind.

Comment: In google chrome you can manage search engine to do something simular(or quite simular) with your adress bar. As a result you can type in adress bar something like '-f game'. I am not sure is there anything like this in IE8. Anyway, if you need this thing in Google Chrome as well, you can find it here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-custom-search-engines-google-chrome/

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Thanks, good to know but I am looking to do it without a server.

Comment: Right; and my answer was that I don't think you can without a server or some type of browser scripting. Chrome would probably be easiest to experiment with, e.g., [content scripts](http://superuser.com/questions/284110/redirect-urls-in-chrome). You have to be able to hook the address bar before it processes, in other words, if you don't want to setup a server.

Comment: @GlenSwift - I just looked at the link that you shared and tried doing what it said but looks like even chrome doesn't allow for keyword to local file mapping. It allows configuring the search better but wouldn't open a local file from just a keyword. But thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish. Atleast for chrome, I will have a look at content scripts.

Comment: You do something wrong. I've just open local file from my desktop by adding next search engine: file://localhost/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Admin/Desktop/%s.txt
And it works fine. I type "-- file" to adress bar and chrome open file.txt from desktop

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling offering a heavy shell-driven-with-registry-manipulation is perhaps more than you'd like to chew (I could be wrong, you might delight in `C++`...).

So here's a fairly straight-forward method using the [venerable `.url`](http://www.fmtz.com/formats/url-file-format/article) in a Favorites folder:

**game.url**

```
[DEFAULT]
BASEURL=url
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,11
[InternetShortcut]
URL=file:\\\C:\path\to\game.html
IDList=
ShowCommand=3
IconIndex=1
IconFile=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\url.dll
HotKey=1601
[MonitoredItem]
PreviewSize=320x240
IsLivePreview=false
```

Save that with the given filename into:

```
C:\Users\[username]\Favorites\Links
```

And then type into the address bar and `game.url` should show up in the list below, under Favorites. I know, not quite what you are after. It's close and *easy*, and (*bonus!*) I believe you can specify a hotkey in the `.url` file and simply hotkey to open (if that floats your boat). I couldn't find a great reference to the `.url` filetype resource syntax, but there is [(Legacy) Internet Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776784%28VS.85%29.aspx).

From here it gets trickier. That may involve creating a [shell `verb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (think `Open` and `Edit` from the context menu), or maybe setting up a protocol handler (?) or a customer search term. It may look like a simple "address" bar, but especially in Internet Explorer, it handles all kinds of input, so it's a bit of a loaded question saying you want to enter *`term`* and get *`file`* without navigating all of that.

Chrome, however, would perhaps be a bit easier to manipulate with content scripts, so I'd look there first.